# Windows 7/10 japanese keyboard language (no IME for hiragana)

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, ime

I have a Swiss-French physical keyboard but I write in Swiss-French, English (International layout) and I would like to write in Japanese too. The thing is that when I set the Japanese layout I can either set IME in which I write in romanji or set the default Japanese layout which doesn't work because it needs more keys to switch between hiragana/katakana/kanji.

Is there a way to switch to a "classic" japanese keyboard without the need of the several other keys to switch between writings ? (like a shortcut instead)

Windows 7 or Windows 10

rXp

Answer (score 0):

### To switch input language:

- Win 7 - `Alt + Shift`
- Win8/Win10 - `Windows Key + Space`

---

### To switch keyboard layout:

- Win 7 - `Ctrl + Shift`
- Win8/Win10 - `Windows Key + Space`

---

### For Japanese language:

- *Windows 7*

  - Change to Hiragana -> `Ctrl + Caps Lock`
  - Kanji -> Press `Space` 1 time to display the most common Kanji for the underlined Hiragana. Press `Space` again for more choices.
  - Change to Katakana -> `Alt + Caps Lock`
  - Toggle between Hiragana and Alphanumeric: `Shift + Caps Lock`
  - Toggle between Last Used and Alphanumeric: `Alt + ~`

Comment: But is there a way for me to get the layout of the japanese keyboard ?
[Japanese layout](https://txcom2003.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/540px-computer-keyboard-japanese-svg1.png)